# show that if a simply connected space has $H_2(X) = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ then it is homotopic to $S^1 \bigwedge S^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

The problem is as follows

> show that if a simply connected CW-complex has $H_2(X) = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_i(X) = 0$ for all $i \neq 2$ then it is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \bigwedge S^2$

I have no idea where to begin. I tried to start out with $S^2 \bigwedge S^1$ but it didn't work.I tried to explicitly xonstruxt such a CW complex but failed.

Any help or hint is appreciated

Comment: If $\wedge$ is supposed to be the smash product, then indeed $S^1\wedge S^2\simeq S^3$, but $S^3$ does not satisfy $H_2(X)=\mathbb{Z}^2$. I suppose you want the wedge sum instead of the smash product (the wedge sum is not denoted by the wedge symbol, which may be the source of confusion..).

Comment: @Thorgott I checked the problem sheet again. It says $S^2 \wedge S^1$ (instead of $S^1 \wedge S^2$)

Comment: @A.Ekbote that doesn't matter: smash product is commutative. Moreover the only CW complex (up to homotopy equivalence) that satisfies your homology conditions is $S^2\vee S^2$, because it is Moore space (see Allen Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology", Exercise 4.34).

Comment: @freakish but $S^2 \vee S^2$ is not homtopy equivalent to $S^2 \wedge S^1$, right?

Comment: That's the same thing (smash product is commutative). If that's really what it says, the statement is incorrect, as I explained in my first comment.

Comment: @A.Ekbote it is not. $S^2\wedge S^1$ is homotopy equivalent (even homeomorphic) to $S^3$ as noted by Thorgott. And so $H_2(S^2\wedge S^1)=H_2(S^3)=0$.

Comment: Ok thank you guys. I see the solution if it were the wedge sum instead of the smash product

Comment: @A.Ekbote no, it is not enough to change $\wedge$ to $\vee$. Read carefuly what I wrote: it is $S^2\vee S^2$. Both spheres are of dimension $2$. None of the homology groups of $S^1\vee S^2$ is $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$, plus it has nontrivial homologies in dimension $1$ and $2$.

Comment: @freakish yes I agree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not correct. First of all the smash product $S^1\wedge S^2$ is homeomorphic to $S^3$. And therefore $H_2(S^3)=0$.

Secondly, it is not a simple matter of replacing the smash product $\wedge$ with the wedge sum $\vee$. Because $H_2(S^1\vee S^2)=\mathbb{Z}$. And besides $S^1\vee S^2$ is not simply connected.

So the correct statement is: it is homotopy equivalent to $S^2\vee S^2$.

And the reason for that is that we are dealing with a Moore space of type $M(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z},2)$. And Moore spaces are unique (up to homotopy equivalence) among CW complexes. This result can be found for example in Allen Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology", exercise 4.34.